# Quantidade de decrementos em um dataframe

Tags: r, comparação

Possuo um data frame onde em cada coluna é o valor de eventos no período, preciso calcular o incremente e o decremento desses períodos para uma base maior e não consegui fazer:

```
p1<- rep(2:11)
p2<- rep(3:12)
p3<- rep(1:10)
p4<- rep(4:13)

base<- cbind(p1,p2,p3,p4)

base
      p1 p2 p3 p4
 [1,]  2  3  1  4
 [2,]  3  4  2  5
 [3,]  4  5  3  6
 [4,]  5  6  4  7
 [5,]  6  7  5  8
 [6,]  7  8  6  9
 [7,]  8  9  7 10
 [8,]  9 10  8 11
 [9,] 10 11  9 12
[10,] 11 12 10 13
```

esperado:

```
       p1 p2 p3 p4 in dc
  [1,]  2  3  1  4  2  1
  [2,]  3  4  2  5  2  1
  [3,]  4  5  3  6  2  1
  [4,]  5  6  4  7  2  1
  [5,]  6  7  5  8  2  1
  [6,]  7  8  6  9  2  1
  [7,]  8  9  7 10  2  1
  [8,]  9 10  8 11  2  1
  [9,] 10 11  9 12  2  1
 [10,] 11 12 10 13  2  1
```

Ou seja, tomando como exemplo a linha 9:

```
[9,] 10 11  9 12  2  1
```

comparando o p2 com o p1 houve um incremento (10 > 11)
para o período 3 houve um decremento (11 > 9)
para o período 4 houve outro incremento (9 > 12) totalizando 2 incrementos e um decremento.

A ideia é executar isso para um conjunto de 500 variáveis visualizadas em 10 períodos.

Comment: Teria como você explicar de forma mais clara o que seria o incremento e o decremento em questão?

Comment: concordo que não estava claro, obrigado pelo feedback, fiz uma alteração veja se me fiz entender!

Comment: O que deve acontecer se não incremento? Por exemplo, se originalmente a linha 9 fosse `10 11 11 12`, qual deveria ser o resultado? `10 11 11 12 2 0`? Ou algo diferente?

Comment: correto, dado que não houve incremento é 0, so preciso contar os incrementos entre as linhas do data frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro usarei a função `diff` para calcular a diferença entre duas colunas consecutivas. É necessário transpor o resultado para que ele fique no mesmo padrão de `base`:

```
diferencas <- t(apply(base, 1, diff))
diferencas
      p2 p3 p4
 [1,]  1 -2  3
 [2,]  1 -2  3
 [3,]  1 -2  3
 [4,]  1 -2  3
 [5,]  1 -2  3
 [6,]  1 -2  3
 [7,]  1 -2  3
 [8,]  1 -2  3
 [9,]  1 -2  3
[10,]  1 -2  3
```

Isto posto, vou contar quantos incrementos há por linha. Isto é, vou contar quantos valores de `diferencas` são maiores do que 0:

```
in <- apply(t(apply(diferencas, 1, function(x) x > 0)), 1, sum)
```

De mono análogo, vou contar quantos decrementos há por linha. Isto é, vou contar quantos valores de `diferencas` são menores do que 0:

```
dc <- apply(t(apply(diferencas, 1, function(x) x < 0)), 1, sum)
```

Note que isto funciona porque, para o `R`, `TRUE` tem valor 1. Agora só preciso juntar os resultados:

```
cbind(base, in, dc)
      p1 p2 p3 p4 in dc
 [1,]  2  3  1  4  2  1
 [2,]  3  4  2  5  2  1
 [3,]  4  5  3  6  2  1
 [4,]  5  6  4  7  2  1
 [5,]  6  7  5  8  2  1
 [6,]  7  8  6  9  2  1
 [7,]  8  9  7 10  2  1
 [8,]  9 10  8 11  2  1
 [9,] 10 11  9 12  2  1
[10,] 11 12 10 13  2  1
```